# I got a problem upgrading packages on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

```
root@ubuntu:~# su
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport apport-gtk apt apt-transport-https apt-utils cinelerra-cv fuse
  libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libfuse2 libguicast1-cv libldap-2.4-2
 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libmpeg3cine-cv libpq5 libquicktimecine-cv libssl1.0.0
  libssl1.0.0:i386 linux-libc-dev openssl python-apport python-problem-report
  thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support upstart virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
  virtualbox-qt
28 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 84.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 11.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

NOTE: I tried bleachbit, sudo apt-get clean, autoclean, etc even dpkg -i --configure -a? and I looked at my root.disk and it says 0.0kb of free room(I think( I don't say verbatim)?) I think there is a bug that causes this problem or I destroyed my system. I have a Dell Vostro 1400 notebook from 2007 with a 1.8Ghz cpu with XD/NX support in the bios enabled, I am not able to fix my problem for my knowledge base is primitive when compared to people with higher experience on Ubuntu Forums. Anything will help. I am still able to use the system and have wifi enabled on Ubuntu OS. Nothing seems to work when I try to apply the security updates it still throws that error.

Comment: From your dash open the "Disks" application and post the results.  It sounds like you may be out of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar problems when following command line instructions to the letter, and I think I know why this is.  What I find works when this happens is to go to the GRAPHICAL update screen and press "check".  Doing so updates the update catalog, or at least that's how I explain it.  It's worth a try and may very well fix your problem.

Please see the "check" button next to the "install updates" button.

[image: The graphical update screen should look similar to this]